# Need to add text file entries to simple one line/command bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Basically I need to execute a curl command multiple times and redirect the output to a .csv file, each time the command is executed a term that is used in two separate places in the command is changed.  I do have a list of these terms (arguments?) contained in a separate text file.  Each time the command runs for a different term, the output needs to be appended to the file.

The command is basically:

```
curl "http://someURL/standardconditions+AND+(TERM_exact+OR+TERM_related)" > testfile.csv
```

So each time the command is run, **TERM** changes in both places (**TERM**_exact and **TERM**_related).  As I mentioned, I have a text file that has a list of all 60 or so terms, what I want is the script to execute the command using the first term on the list, write the output to the specified .csv file and then repeat with the second term on the list, append that to the file and so on and so forth until it's been run for every single term.

I imagine there is a simple way to do this, I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it,

This assumes that `listFile.csv` is your list of 60 items, and that each line is a comma-separated pair of values (no commas allowed in values!)

```
while IFS=, read exact related ; do
   curl "http://someURL/standardconditions+AND+(TERM_${exact}+OR+TERM_${related})" >> testfile.csv
done < listFile.csv
```

It's not clear if you wanted one output file, or multiple.

You could replace the `>> testfile.csv` with `>>testfile.${exact}_${related}.csv`
to have separate files.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to store TERM, and use concat function to get a string like 
"http://someURL/standardconditions+AND+(TERM_exact+OR+TERM_related)", and run a python(may be other language)script including loop structure to handle 60 terms.